# How do I create a global variable in R which can be used within functions and sql statements?

Tags: r, global-variables

I would like to define a global variable in R that can be used in functions and sqldf statements. My goal is to change the variable I would like to include one time, at the top of my code - and use this throughout. This will really save me time, and I have been unable to find a solution by searching the forums.

```
# define variable
    myvar <<- as.name('cyl')

# use within a sql statement
    library("sqldf")

    sqldf('
        select 
            avg(myvar)
        from 
            mtcars
        ')

# use within a regression
    reg<-lm(mpg ~ myvar, data=mtcars)
    summary(reg)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can substitute an R variable into a SQL statement like that.  I seem to remember my professor mentioning that it's not possible

Comment: @Richard Scriven: Thanks for the input - any idea about replacing the variable in R statements (such as the regerssion)? I can replace the sql code with R functions.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289295.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to create the query string from a variable

```
myvar <- 'cyl'

query <- sprintf('select avg(%s) from mtcars', myvar)

library("sqldf")

sqldf(query)
```

And `get` to retrieve the value in the model design:

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ get(myvar), data=mtcars)
summary(reg)
```

As James mentions in the comments, this may be preferable to `get`:

```
reg <- lm(formula(paste('mpg~', myvar)), data=mtcars)
```

Comment: You might find `as.formula(paste("mpg~",myvar))` to be preferable to get.

Comment: Zelazny - you saved the day!! I love the "get" solution - perfect.

Comment: Or `do.call("lm", list(substitute(some stuff))`, as opposed to `get`

Answer (score 1):

Unless we are setting `myvar` from within a function we can just use `<-` instead of `<<-` .

Prefacing `sqldf`, `lm` (or any function call) with `fn$` from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) (which is automatically loaded by the [sqldf package](http://sqldf.googlecode.com)) allows the use of quasi-perl style string interpolation as shown in [Example 5 on the sqldf home page](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables).  Below we use `fn$sqldf` and `fn$lm` in the first two exampoles. An alternative to `fn$lm` shown in the third example is to use `eval(substitute(...))` .

A noteable feature of the code below is that the codes are all quite simple.

A second important feature of the `lm` code below is that the output of both `lm` examples show the formula with `myvar` *already substituted* which is useful when you look at it later to know the actual value that was used.  That is, the first `lm` example below does not display the formula as `mpg ~ $myvar` (even though that is what we input) but displays it as `mpg ~ cyl` in the output.  Similarly the last `lm` example does not display the formula as `mpg ~ myvar` as input but displays it in the output as `mpg ~ cyl`.

The first `lm` example will still work if we write `mtcars` rather than `quote(mtcars)`; however, the output will not look very nice.  The need for this is due to the fact that `lm` uses non-standard evaluation of its arguments.

```
myvar <- as.name("cyl") # use <<- if done within a function

library(sqldf)
fn$sqldf("select avg($myvar) from mtcars")

fn$lm("mpg ~ $myvar", quote(mtcars))
```

or the following in place of the last line:

```
eval(substitute(lm(mpg ~ myvar, data = mtcars), list(myvar = myvar)))
```